# Android Studio google map not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android and m trying to implement google map in my app.
i generated API Key following all the procedures mentioned but i am not getting the output. It is simple showing grey area with google written on left side of the page . my code is as follows . i have generated apk file and testing in mobile.I have enabled Google Maps Android API also

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**AndroidManisfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.namrathasrinivas.maps" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
             Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
        -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyACVUB1GlGgdtbiJEK-C0P35jKTOZvJfCQ" />


            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <activity
                android:name=".MapsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: post your fragment + xml layouts

Comment: make sure that when you enabled google Maps api, you wrote the right package name and the right sha1 recheck the value of sha1.
plus try to run standard google maps app from a device and see if it works, so you make sure it is not a network failure

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `Google Maps Android API` in the `https://console.developers.google.com` then only you can able view the map

Comment: i forgot to mention that. i have enabled.

Comment: did u add the com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0 dependencies in build.gradle

Comment: no you don't actually need to add that if you were using eclipse, it is just like including a library; plus even tho if you are using android studio, and it doesn't give you syntax error then it is probably included in your project.

Comment: right click on project ->module setting ->dependencies tab->click on +icon then add com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0